# About variable swapping

Tags: calculus

Is this statement true?

If we have a map (linear or not linear) $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x,y)+f(y,x)=C$ $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, then f is a constant map.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to think of simple examples for these types of problems. $f(x,y)=x-y$.